# Tensorboard AVX2 error when using GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, jupyter-notebook

At the moment I have both Tensorflow CPU and GPU installed for use in Jupyter Notebook. 
Beforehand, I used the CPU-version, as I did not require GPU-performance. However, now I am training an Inception model with my GPU, and I want to access the Tensorboard.

The problem I had before with the CPU version was the error:
`Your CPU supports instructions that this Tensorflow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2`. I have read about AVX2 in other Stackoverflow questions, and I understand that this was due to the cpu-version of Tensorflow I used.

However, now I am training a model with the GPU-version of Tensorflow (in Jupyter Notebook, I created a new kernel that supports this), but even now when I try to access the Tensorboard with: 
`tensorboard --logdir=. (directory here)` it keeps referring to the above error, like it is not acknowledging that I am now using the gpu (I have checked in Notebook, GPU is running instead of CPU).

Anyone familiar with this issue? 
I use `tensorflow 1.7.0` as well as `tensorboard 1.7.0`

Comment: Its not an error message, just ignore it.

Comment: Well, when I go to `localhost:6006` it says the page cannot be reached, and that localhost refused connection. What is causing this issue then?

Comment: Well its not lack of AVX2, maybe you should include the actual tensorboard output in your question.

Answer (score 4):

The error you have is not an error - it's a hint to tell you that you can use your AVX2 instructions to optimize the compilation of the tensorflow DSL that you made.

Refer to [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources) tutorial from tensorflow to compile your tensorflow from source. What you download via `pip`, or `conda`, or etc are actually *precompiled binaries* that supports a wide array of different computers - some of which **don't have AVX2 instructions**. `bazel` is the build system that tensorflow decided to use to build their source code into its respective binaries, and you will use this to specify your installation flags.

By default, bazel will be called to build with flags `-march=native`, which tries to build with the best configurations for the CPU it's looking at.

After you have successfully set up your environment for installation, make sure to call bazel with:

```
-c opt --copt=-mavx --copt=-mavx2
```

which means support AVX and AVX2 instructions during compilation.

I built my tensorflow with avx2 instructions and I saw a noticeable speed difference. It is not relevant to your tensorboard issue.

Comment: I know that AVX2 set makes tensorflow train faster on CPU-only mode by 20% at least; but have you noticed a noticeable difference while training on GPU?